# How to delete and add certificates to this Azure / Web Publish certificate location?

Tags: azure, certificate

I have created a management certificate for use with Windows Azure. I created it via IIS. I have uploaded to the Azure Management Portal and now I need to to select it when publishing a site to my Azure Account. This is the dialog I am referring to:

[image]

The problem is that even though i have installed the certificate I have created, it does not show up in the list AND besides that there are a bunch of old test certs etc that i would like to delete.

**How do I manage the location that this dialog is pointing too?**

I do know how to use this dialog to create yet another certificate and then upload that again to Windows Azure Management Portal but then I'd just be working around my ignorance of this "problem" and I'd actually prefer to understand what Im looking at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this Url:

[Setting Up Named Authentication Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683676.aspx)

> To be available to use with the Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio,
>   a certificate must have a private key and must be installed in the
>   Personal store on the local computer.

Therefore all the items in the dialog's list will be getting pulled from the Personal Certificate Store of the current user.

To confirm this go to Start>Run and type "mmc"

That will bring up a management console window. Within that windows go

```
File>Add Remove / Snap In
```

Within the dialog that opens add Certificates and then choose User Account.

Now you have an MMC to manage your certificates. Within the MMC you just created expand the certificates window and select Personal.

Within that list you will find all the entries that the dialog is using and can remove them at will. To install the certificate you have already created just use the Import option and you should be good to go.

..

Richard

Comment: That works if i add the extra step of first exporting the management certificate that i import into the Personal certificate store as a pfx. I did that by going back to IIS and exporting the certificate that i uploaded to Windows Azure and entering a password etc. I then imported that as you have described above into Personal Certificates. If i didn't do that it still would show up in the dialog even though it was in ther Personal Certificates location.

Comment: Above i meant to say: "If i didn't do that it still would NOT show up in the dialog even though it was in the Personal Certificates location." i.e. It has to be signed .pfx not just a .cer for this dialog to pick it up so it's not just location but location AND authority.

Answer (score 1):

Though my answer is not related to this question but there has been some significant improvement in Windows Azure SDK (SDK 1.6) around deployment experience through Visual Studio which would take away a lots of hassles around creating/uploading management certficates, so I thought I should mention it here. Please take a look at the following links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/neilhut/archive/2011/11/15/windows-azure-sdk-november-update.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh535756.aspx

Essentially now what you can do is download a "Publish Profile" file which contains information about all your subscriptions and the management certificate required by Visual Studio to work with your subscription using Service Management API. The neat thing about this is that when you download the publish profile file (Refer to the 2nd link) it automatically adds a certificate in your management certificates (thus removing the two step process of creating a certificate on your computer and uploading them in the portal).